# Correct warning : "Expected to return a value in arrow function array-callback-return "

Tags: javascript, foreach, find

I want to correct the warning

> Expected to return a value in arrow function array-callback-return".

I tried adding `return` but the problem still exists.

```
listTaskWorkflow.forEach(element => {
    workflowDetail.department.departmentsList.find(department => {
        if (department.idDept === element.idDept) 
            element.idDept = department.departmentName;          
    })
});
```

Comment: Don't use `find` if you're not trying to find an element by a condition and do something with the result.

Comment: Please don't include line numbers in your code blocks. It makes it difficult to copy them to show how to change them.

Answer (score 0):

[`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) expects you to tell it whether the item it's calling you back with is the item you're looking for. To use it in that code, you'd leave the `idDept` check in the `find` but then use the array element it returns:

```
listTaskWorkflow.forEach(element => {
    const department = workflowDetail.department.departmentsList.find(department => department.idDept === element.idDept);
    if (department) {
        element.idDept = department.departmentName;          
    }
});
```

Another option, though, would be to use a `for-of` loop:

```
listTaskWorkflow.forEach(element => {
    for (const department of workflowDetail.department.departmentsList) {
        if (department.idDept === element.idDept) {
            element.idDept = department.departmentName;          
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

You could use `for-of` instead of `forEach` as well if you wanted:

```
for (const element of listTaskWorkflow) {
    for (const department of workflowDetail.department.departmentsList) {
        if (department.idDept === element.idDept) {
            element.idDept = department.departmentName;          
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mixing them looks weird. I'd recommend using `for … of` twice, or using `forEach` twice (not that I'd eve recommend `forEach`…)

Comment: @Bergi - I did point out in the answer that the OP might use `for-of` instead of `forEach` as well. Using `forEach` twice wouldn't make sense, you want the short-circuiting when you find the right department.

Comment: Thank you @T.J. Crowder
 it works ,it's a very good idea